# REDUX: Why won't the store provide data to my component?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Newbie here trying to learn some Redux. 
GOAL: to get a button to click and login/logout, updating the store as true/false status whichever way.

`const store = createStore(myReducer)`
Created my store, passing in my reducer.

This has a default state of logged out. And returns the opposite, whenever the button is clicked.

I know this action works through debugging.

```
function myReducer(state = { isLoggedIn: false }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
    return {
      isLoggedIn: !state.isLoggedIn
    }
    default:
    return state
  }
}
```

The problem starts here - when i *try* to access the store.getState() data.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Login Status: { state.isLoggedIn }</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.login}>Login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Main status={store.getState().isLoggedIn} login={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE' })}/>,     document.getElementById('root'));
}

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

I've tried store.getState().isLoggedIn & store.getState() & this.props.status and then assigning the store.getState().isLoggedIn in the Main component - but nothing works.

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't directly access the store using `getState` to find data. The [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) explain the process in-depth, but basically you'll connect each component to the Redux store using `connect` method of the `react-redux` package.

Here's an example of how this could work for your above component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Main from '../components/Main'

class MainContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Main {...this.props} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  login() {
    dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE'})
  },
})

MainContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(MainContainer)

export default MainContainer
```

You would then want to render the `MainContainer` in place of the `Main` component. The container will pass down `isLoggedIn` and `login` as props to `Main` when it renders it.

Comment: Thanks @MarkChandler - i was following the Dan Abramov tutorial and his todos (& therefore toggle todo) list doesn't seem to use mapStateToProps yet, at that toggle stage?

Perhaps i'm getting ahead of myself - but is connect() and the above necessary if you just want to show loggedin 'true' or 'false' in a div?

Comment: @NewbieAid: You can access the state other ways, like importing the store from the file its created in and calling `store.getState()`, but this is the idiomatic way to do things. I'd say you're getting ahead of yourself though, as I know he gets into `mapStateToProps` later.

Dan also has two free video walkthroughs for Redux on egghead.io that go into some pretty advanced topics. I definitely recommend them if you learn well from videos!

Comment: yeah i'm on the Egghead ones at the moment, thanks. It's just doing my nut because the idea of having a toggle button that logs in or out (true/false) and then displaying that seems *so* simple. & i can get it showing in the console... so yeah, i've been banging my head against the screen for 5 hours! haha.