# How to get stored data from store.getState()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have using react with redux for the first time.

In my app's render, if I console log `store.getState()` I can see the stored data `{username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}`

but when I want to get the data like `store.getState().password`

I get `undefined error`. I am trying to pass this data to 
my components for private route as:

inside PrivateRoute I then try to check if the user is logged in or not to send to dashboard

so, how do I get data to pass to my props?

even `const { isLoggedIn, username } = store.getState()` doesn't work, it shows

Property `isLoggedIn` does not exist on type `{}`

btw I know this might be bad but it's my first react app so I am trying to learn redux

Comment: hey, please share some code and you problem that you are facing

Comment: there is no code, it's just one component and I need get data from `store.getState()` because I can see the data is in there, but how do I get the store from it?

Comment: Please refer to possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266720/redux-why-wont-the-store-provide-data-to-my-component?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are calling the store from the react application you have to use provider and pass the store to the react app, and then bind state, actions and/or methods of the store  to the react props as shown in this link

> connect https://react-redux.js.org/5.x/api/connect

but if you are using redux in normal javascript then it will work fine.

example in react

first

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from "store";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <YourReactApp/>  // e.g <Container />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

then in you can bind anything from your store to react component like this

```
 import { connect } from "react-redux";

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const { isLoggedIn, username }= state
      return {
        isLoggedIn,
  username
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch :any) => {
        return {
          login: ()=> { 
            return dispatch(your action creator)
          }
        }
      }



    const Containter = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(AnyReactComponentYouWantToPassThisStore);

    export default Containter;
```

the you can use it in your page like this

```
function AnyReactComponentYouWantToPassThisStore (props){
  return(
<div> {props.username}  </div>
)
}
```

then instead of calling `<AnyReactComponentYouWantToPassThisStore />`

now use  `<Container />`

Comment: in react, store is not called like this const { isLoggedIn, username } = store.getState()